# PHP: testing for existence of a cell in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array with numerous dimensions, and I want to test for the existence of a cell.

The below cascaded approach, will be for sure a safe way to do it:

```
if (array_key_exists($arr, 'dim1Key'))  
  if (array_key_exists($arr['dim1Key'], 'dim2Key'))  
    if (array_key_exists($arr['dim1Key']['dim2Key'], 'dim3Key'))  
      echo "cell exists";
```

But is there a simpler way?

I'll go into more details about this:

1. Can I perform this check in one single statement?
2. Do I have to use array_key_exist or can I use something like isset? When do I use each and why?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`isset()` is the cannonical method of testing, even for multidimensional arrays. Unless you need to know exactly which dimension is missing, then something like

```
isset($arr[1][2][3])
```

is perfectly acceptable, even if the `[1]` and `[2]` elements aren't there (3 can't exist unless 1 and 2 are there).

However, if you have

```
$arr['a'] = null;
```

then

```
isset($arr['a']); // false
array_key_exists('a', $arr); // true
```

comment followup:

Maybe this analogy will help. Think of a PHP variable (an actual variable, an array element, etc...) as a cardboard box:

- `isset()` looks inside the box and figures out if the box's contents can be typecast to  something that's "not null". It doesn't care if the box exists or not - it only cares about the box's contents. If the box doesn't exist, then it obviously can't contain anything.
- `array_key_exists()` checks if the box itself exists or not. The contents of the box are irrelevant, it's checking for traces of cardboard.

Comment: Thanks. If so, why should one ever use array_key_exists?

Comment: @gidireich: for exactly that reason. To be able to differentiate between a key existing and having a `null` value, and a key not existing at all. Which is only a reason if you care about it.

Comment: with `isset` your checking if the key and value exists or is not null, with `array_key_exists` your checking if the **key** exists regardless if the values is `null`

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem, except i needed it for some Drupal stuff. I also needed to check if objects contained items as well as arrays. Here's the code I made, its a recursive search that looks to see if objects contain the value as well as arrays. Thought someone might find it useful.

```
function recursiveIsset($variable, $checkArray, $i=0) {
    $new_var = null;
    if(is_array($variable) && array_key_exists($checkArray[$i], $variable))
        $new_var = $variable[$checkArray[$i]];
    else if(is_object($variable) && array_key_exists($checkArray[$i], $variable))
        $new_var = $variable->$checkArray[$i];
    if(!isset($new_var))
        return false;

    else if(count($checkArray) > $i + 1)
        return recursiveIsset($new_var, $checkArray, $i+1);
    else
        return $new_var;
}
```

Use: **For instance**

```
recursiveIsset($variables, array('content', 'body', '#object', 'body', 'und'))
```

In my case in drupal this ment for me that the following variable existed

```
$variables['content']['body']['#object']->body['und']
```

due note that just because '#object' is called object does not mean that it is. My recursive search also would return true if this location existed

```
$variables->content->body['#object']->body['und']
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fast one liner you can use [has method](https://minwork.gitbook.io/array/common-methods/has) from [this array library](https://github.com/minwork/array):

```php
Arr::has('dim1Key.dim2Key.dim3Key')
```

Big benefit is that you can use dot notation to specify array keys which makes things simpler and more elegant.

Also, this method will work as expected for `null` value because it internally uses `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `$arr['dim1Key']['dim2Key']['dim3Key']`, to be safe you need to check if all arrays exist before `dim3Key`. Then you can use `array_key_exists`.

So yes, there is a simpler way using one single `if` statement like the following:

```
if (isset($arr['dim1Key']['dim2Key']) &&
    array_key_exists('dim3Key', $arr['dim1Key']['dim2Key'])) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating a helper function like the following:

```
function my_isset_multi( $arr,$keys ){
    foreach( $keys as $key ){
        if( !isset( $arr[$key] ) ){
            return false;
        }
        $arr = $arr[$key];
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Then in my code, I first check the array using the function above, and if it doesn't return false, it will return the array itself.

Imagine you have this kind of array:

```
$arr = array( 'sample-1' => 'value-1','sample-2' => 'value-2','sample-3' => 'value-3' );
```

You can write something like this:

```
$arr = my_isset_multi( $arr,array( 'sample-1','sample-2','sample-3' ) );

if( $arr ){
    //You can use the variable $arr without problems
}
```

The function my_isset_multi will check for every level of the array, and if a key is not set, it will return false.