# How to check if the nested property exists in SimpleXML

Tags: php

I would like to get rid of "Trying to get property of non-object" warnings, but couldn't figure out the correct syntax for checking the existance of properties in my case.

```
$this->nonce = $syncbod->Status->Chal->Meta->NextNonce;
```

Trying to call

```
property_exists($syncbod, "Status->Chal")
```

returns always false. What would be the correct way to check if `Chal` exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576671/php-testing-for-existence-of-a-cell-in-a-multidimensional-array), although the question applies to arrays, the same principal applies to the SimpleXml properties. The question was more of a reference to the nested part then the array part

Comment: This link is about arrays, but in my case its class properties

Comment: I know, the question is about arrays but also applies to SimpleXml

Comment: $test = [1 => 'test'];

var_dump(
 isset($test[1]), /* true */
 isset($test[1][2]), /*true (see below)*/
 isset($test[1][2][3]), /*false*/
 isset($lol[1]) /*false*/
); The second one surprised me, until i realised that a string can be accessed as an array, so $test[1][2] returns "s"